# How to create a navigation menu dynamically in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to provide the navigation menu dynamically by an `angularjs` controller:

`index.html`:

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="navi">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="nav in navigations">
                <a href="{{nav.path}}">{{nav.name}}</a>
            </li>
        <ul>
    </div>
    <script src="js/navi.js"></script>
</body>
```

`navi.js`:

```
 angular.module('app').controller('navi') {
        $scope.navigations = [
            {"path": "www.google.de", "name": "Google"},
            {"path": "www.bing.de", "name": "Bing"},
        ];
    }
```

Result: blank page. Why?

Comment: this isn't even the valid syntax for defining a controller.

Comment: Jep, sorry it just came to my mind hitting the post button. Added answer below in case anyone has the same problem sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, of course one has to use the `function($scope)` for this to work:

```
angular.module('app').controller('navi', function($scope) {
...
});
```